# Convert GET Request (HTML string) to a full DOM object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm writing a JavaScript script that periodically checks for new elements within a page, that is, DOM tree updates. One of those specific elements contains an hyperlink to other page. My objective is to perform a GET of that page and convert the results to a DOM object in order to trigger a particular event of a particular element within that page. I could do this by `var newPage = window.open(hyperlink);` and then have access to the elements within the page through `newPage.document.getElementById('elementId');`. However, the script iterates over many hyperlinks and it is not efficient to open them all up.

So, is there any way to manipulate an object of an entire page efficiently, i.e., without opening it (e.g., `$.get(hyperlink, function(page) { // convert page to DOM });`)?

Appreciate any answers,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're taking the wrong approach.  Rather than convert the page to DOM, you should simply do a regex search for a link.  That would clearly be the most efficient way to make use of a page's contents.  However, admittedly, it is also a pain to do properly and it doesn't take into consideration links added by javascript.

It depends entirely on what your scope is.  If you tell me you're looking for an efficient way of accomplishing this, then I offer this solution.  Otherwise, there's no "quick" way of parsing an entire page into DOM no matter which way you slice it.

[This will get you started on a regular expression for extracting html links.](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=903)

Comment: How come? How would a regex search for a link would help me trigger an event of a particular element within a new requested page?

Comment: Then it's more complicated than I initially thought.  You want to load a page, find its links, and load pages of those links so that you can trigger events on it?  The regex can still help you, but only to retrieve the links and load them.  The page in which you'll need to trigger events on will have to be loaded into its own iframe.  Use css tricks to make it vanish from the page (without using display: none since that will remove it entirely).  Is this what you were asking?